# How can we prove that $f(r)= \sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac{(re^{i\theta})^n}{n}$ from $(-1,1) \to \mathbb C$ is differentiable in $(-1,1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

- How can we prove that $$f(r)= \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(re^{i\theta})^n}{n}$$
  $f$ defined on $(-1,1) \to \mathbb C$ is differentiable in $(-1,1)$?
- This is a function concerning complex numbers. It's not difficult to show that$$f'(r)=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{1-re^{i\theta}}, r\in(-1,1).$$ However, what is confusing me is how to write precisely about the fact that $f$ is differentiable.
- I hope that you can help me solve the confusion!

Comment: It is a power series in $\;r\;$ with convergence radius $\;R=1\;$ and it is thus differentiable within the convergence interval...

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\;f(r)\;$ is a power series in $\;r\;$ with convergence radius $\;R=1\;$ and it is thus differentiable within the convergence interval, namely $\;(-1,1)\;$ .

You may want to check this: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch6.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

It is the composition of the map: $\;\begin{aligned}[t](-1,1)&\longrightarrow\mathbf C\\[-1ex] r&\longmapsto r\mathrm e^{i\theta}\end{aligned}$, which is differentiable as a restriction of a linear map from $\mathbf R$ to $\mathbf C$, by the analytic function $\displaystyle z\longmapsto \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{z^n}n$.